# perl gunzip to buffer and gunzip to file have different byte orders

Tags: gzip, gunzip, perl, storable

I'm using Perl v5.22.1, [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) 2.53_01, and [`IO::Uncompress::Gunzip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) 2.068.

I want to use Perl to gunzip a `Storable` file in memory, without using an intermediate file.

I have a variable `$zip_file = '/some/storable.gz'` that points to this zipped file.

If I gunzip directly to a file, this works fine, and `%root` is correctly set to the `Storable` hash.

```perl
gunzip($zip_file, '/home/myusername/Programming/unzipped');
my %root = %{retrieve('/home/myusername/Programming/unzipped')};
```

However if I gunzip into memory like this:

```perl
my $file;
gunzip($zip_file, \$file);
my %root = %{thaw($file)};
```

I get the error

> ```
> Storable binary image v56.115 more recent than I am (v2.10)`
> ```

so the Storable's magic number has been butchered: it should never be that high.

However, the strings in the unzipped buffer are still correct; the buffer starts with `pst` which is the correct `Storable` header. It only seems to be multi-byte variables like integers which are being broken.

Does this have something to do with byte ordering, such that writing to a file works one way while writing to a file buffer works in another? How can I gunzip to a buffer without it ruining my integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not related to unzip but to using `retrieve` vs. `thaw`. They both expect different input, i.e. `thaw` expect the output from `freeze` while `retrieve` expects the output from `store`.
This can be verified with a simple test:

```
$ perl -MStorable -e 'my $x = {}; store($x,q[file.store])'
$ perl -MStorable=freeze -e 'my $x = {}; print freeze($x)' > file.freeze
```

On my machine this gives 24 bytes for the file created by `store` and 20 bytes for `freeze`. If I remove the leading 4 bytes from `file.store` the file is equivalent to `file.freeze`, i.e. store just added a 4 byte header. Thus you might try to uncompress the file in memory, remove the leading 4 bytes and run `thaw` on the rest.

Comment: This was right! Unfortunately, I didn't create the Storable files so I'm not able to choose to use freeze instead of store. However I found it's still possible to retrieve a `store` Storable in memory by converting $file into a file handle: `open my $fake_fh, "<", \$file;` and then using `fd_retrieve($fake_fh);`